# Concurrently updating database table column value only once

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, concurrency

I have a Postgres table named `mytable` which I am using from JPA/Hibernate entity to manage it.

The table has a column name `mycolumn` with default value set as FALSE.

Now there will be many concurrent update to that column and I want only to update if and only if value is `FALSE`, and once it is updated to `TRUE` by any of one, no other concurrent requests must be able to update it, never ever, resulting in something like 'Value has been already updated and you can not update it.'

AFAIK Locking is not going to help with this.

How to handle this with JPA/Hibernate in concurrent situation?

Thanks

**Edit:** revise title

Comment: `update mytable  set value = newvalue where id = myid and mycolumn = FALSE`

Comment: why you think locking won't help here?.. you use subquery to select candidates?..

Comment: @VaoTsun, Locking will help for concurrent access but how for only one time update?

Comment: one time update? what about it? you just update. sorry - I dont follow then

Comment: Locking absolutely would help with this. Optimistic concurrency control ("optimistic locking" in Hibernate-speak) is pretty much MADE for this. Pessimistic locking would also work, it'd just suck for performance in this case due to the need for a select-for-update, test column and conditional update.